# Taking an Interest based Loan for emergency

Tags: loan

Assalamualaikum warahmathullahi wabarakathuhu readers.

May Allah reward you with jannathul firdaus - aameen.. May Allah give you peace and protect you from sins - ameen.

My question is regarding whether I can take a Interest based Bank loan to pay my debts.

We have a own house which we no longer live in. Initially in my childhood my parents bought this house with bank loan. And after several years of paying more interest, with the help of someone they decided to give the house for lease and take back the house documents from bank from that lease money as they came to know that the bank was cheating them.

It's been around 13 years as of today. Still we are struggling to finish of this debt. We are shifting lease customers like once the current agreement is over and the customer wants to leave the house we bring in a new customer and send out the current one with that money. This is what is happening for several years. We tried our best to do some savings in the meanwhile duration. But that was not successful. My parents also dont make that much money. I also make a fair amount of money. Not much.

Now my problem is.. my parents are getting older. My mom also gets frustrated often because of that old house often bothering us. Also personally we have had some problems in that old house.

Now the current guy who lives in our house for lease wants his money back in 2 months to vacate. We got no money and there is no one whom we know of who could help us. The amount is quite big. 4 and half lakhs INR.

So, what I planned is I could take a loan and pay the debt off and ready the house and sell it and repay the loan and live happily with my parents.

I know loan is haraam. But I am in a dilemma for about 3 to 4 years whether I should go with the Loan or not.

We tried brokers to sell that house. But no result. Because the house is a bad condition, we need to make it ready to either sell it or lease it. But I heard recently that the leasing is also not allowed in islam.. pls advice..

So we tried selling, leasing.. but no result.

Currently we live in a rented house far away from the old house. We were facing many problems in that old house. Like neighbours troubling. Water problem. Maintenance problem. The house builder is a strange man and he never cares about the house. We were very shy to even invite guests to home due to torn walls, water leakage from top. Cockroaches all the kitchen. Heat. Power cuts. Oh common.. despite that we were living happily.. by the grace of Allah.

Seeking some good advice...

Comment: The general answer would be its haram and the targeted answer is still haram. Here is a link to a similar question of yours on IslamQA https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9054/ruling-on-taking-an-interest-based-loan-for-an-urgent-need

Comment: @NanoAdam  jazakallahu khair. Well there must be some exceptions in my case. I believe there might be some..

Comment: then you might want to talk with a local Imam  who could help you in this case. A suggestion might be to look around you, maybe some Muslim families might understand your case and be willing to loan you some money, that would be the ideal situation.

Comment: @NanoAdam  Jazakallahu khair brother.. that was expected..